# Method contract without Traits in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add some re-usability to a Java library which has some common methods across classes, but whose methods are not part of a common hierarchy. I'm pretty certain I've seen it previously that Scala allows non-trait based contracts for parameter classes, but for the life of me I cannot find this information anywhere at the moment.

Does my memory serve me correctly? Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction for documentation on said language feature (if I am not mistaken)?

For some added context, I'm trying to reduce duplicate code when using some Google Java libraries where things like getNextPageToken(), setPageToken(), etc. are common between many classes, but are not implemented further up in the hierarchy where I would have the option to specify a common parent class as the parameter type. So essentially I'd like to enforce that these methods exist and offload the duplicate request & pagination code to a common function using said method contracts.

Comment: maybe you want this? `def method(param: { def getNextPageToken(): Unit })` so the param will be required to have getNextPageToken method with no parameters and returning  `Unit`. It is handled using reflection.

Comment: Fantastic. I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. (appears that's called "Structural Typing" upon further googling).

Comment: Follow-up question: My IDE flags my parameter class passed in as being invalid. It looks like I cannot use this to enforce against a Java class. Does that sound like an accurate statement? (I'm assuming so, as I just whipped up a skeleton class in Scala which passes without errors just fine)

Comment: It seems to work for me, maybe types are wrong or something like this. I created scala class that accepts `String => Unit` and a java class with method `String => void` and I can pass it to scala class in scala code. I can also call this acceptor class from java code, but there the expected type is object and exception is thrown if you pass wrong one. If you will still have problem, maybe let me know what exact types are you using and how you want to call it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I might have to double check my types, I'll take a look at the code and see what the issue might be. In the meantime, if you'd like to post your initial comment as an answer then I'll go ahead and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use structural types:

example:

```
def method(param: { def getNextPageToken(): Unit })
```

`param` will be required to have `getNextPageToken` method with no parameters and returning `Unit`. It is handled using reflection.